# MVC - Load different views depending on user OR load the same view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I'm building a website that has 3 user groups, lets **X, Y and Z**.

On my controller, I'm currently doing the following:

```
if(user_group="X"){
//logic goes here
load_view("X");
}
elseif(user_group="Y"){
//logic goes here
load_view("Y");
}
elseif(user_group="Z"){
//logic goes here
load_view("Z");
}
```

The reason why I'm doing this is because each user is supposed to load a completely different page, users basically don't share anything in common in what they see, so I thought it would look cleaner to load a different view depending on the user group.

I could just load the same view for different users:

```
if($user="X"){
//view HTML
}
elseif($user="Y"){
//view HTML
}
elseif($user="Z"){
//view HTML
}
```

What would you do in these circumstances? Load different views? Load the same view? I 'grew up' hearing about leaving programming logic out of views, so I'm just wondering here what the community thinks it's better.

Comment: Using ifelse in this is not correct. What will you do if in other day appears +5 groups. I'd use the methods like
getGroupView($group_id) {} which will render view and render 404 if group does not exists. Should be Exception if view template does not exists

Comment: The coding isn't really important right now, it's more a logic thing atr this point, that code up there was just something I typed quick to translate my bad explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the views are different enough for the different types of users to legitimately require separate views/HTML for each.

If that's the case, I would find it easier to load the appropriate view in the controller. That would result in 3 smaller HTML/view files to maintain rather than one LARGE one.

It's really just a matter of preference.

> I 'grew up' hearing about leaving programming logic out of views

Yeah, me too...but we can carry that idea too far...sometimes it's essential and necessary, other times it's useful. I'd rather be pragmatic than dogmatic.